# how can i connect arduino and gazebo

Tags: ros, arduino, gazebo, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

i'm trying to make an aplication with a flex sensor in arduino, the flex sensor change the value of the resistance when is deflected and i wanna see this change with the movement of a object in gazebo, someone could help me with that....

thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47450/how-can-i-connect-arduino-and-gazebo/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2012-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to do that fairly easily by using rosserial. Read the flex in the arduino and just publish the correct message/service you need to gazebo. The only problem might be if that message is too large for the arduino, then you would need to put a node in between.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0